# Usar una imagen con Glide y Tint en android

Tags: android, android-glide

Buenas comunidad, mi problema es el siguiente:

Estoy inflando imagenes con la librería de Glide ya que poniendo la ruta de la imagen directamente en el `xml` hace que mi app vaya más lenta.

En el `xml` tengo el siguiente código para una imagen:

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_principal_login"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:contentDescription="@null"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:tint="@color/colorPrimaryLight"
        android:tintMode="screen" />
```

Y en código el siguiente código de glide:

```
Glide.with(this).load(R.drawable.mijares_cascada).into(imgPrincipal);
```

El problema es que el código del `tint` no se aplica aunque está puesto en el `xml`, es decir, este código que hace que la imagen tenga un tono de color distinto:

> android:tint="@color/colorPrimaryLight"
>               android:tintMode="screen"

---

**AMPLIACIÓN**

He probado también a hacerlo desde código después de inflar la imagen con el glide de esta forma pero tampoco funciona:

```
    Glide.with(this).load(R.drawable.mijares_cascada).into(imgPrincipal);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        imgPrincipal.setImageTintList(getColorStateList(R.color.colorPrimaryLight));
    }
    imgPrincipal.setImageTintMode(PorterDuff.Mode.SCREEN);
```

Comment: prueba con GlideApp.with(this).load(null).error(R.drawable.mijares_cascada).into(imgPrincipal);

Comment: No se puede hacer un load de un null

Comment: prueba con Glide 4.1.1, creo que han solucionado parte que los drawables locales no los carga bien https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues/1532 y aqui tambien puedes allar solución https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues/1261